# Get a 3D or 4D array as input and reshape it to 2D array in a function from external script

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, user-defined-functions, reshape

Okay, my question is a little more specific than reshaping a 3D or 4D array to a 2D array.

I am writing a script for front end processing of 3D or 4D arrays.

I want to call a function from an external script for which a 3D array will be supplied as the ONLY input. The desired output should be a 2D array.

To elaborate even more, the 3D or 4D array will be of dimensions (x,y,t) or (x,y,z,t) where x,y,and z are spatial dimensions and t being the time. Basically this is how an unsteady flow data is contained.

Now I want to reshape this into a 2D array with shape ([x*y*z, t]). However, this should be done with only the multidimensional array as the input. I wouldn't want to pass x,y,z, and t as input.

Could someone help me write a function for this?

Something like,

def frontend(data):

- check data.shape
- obtain x,y,z,t values using len(data) commands
- reshape the data into ([x*y*z, t])
- return reshaped data

UPDATE: I am sorry for not being very clear. The problem I am exactly having is about the shape. For example, I have 100 steps in the x direction, 50 steps in the y direction, 10 steps in the z direction, and 20 steps in the temporal direction. That is the array has dimensions ([100,50,10,20]). Now, I need to reshape this ([100,50,10,20]) array to ([50000,20]) array. This can be done with the normal 'reshape' command. Now, the problem is that, I am supplying only the data array into the function from an external script and I do not know its dimensions. I need to find the X dimension, Y dimension, Z dimension, and t dimension of the array, and then I need to reshape this 4D array into a 2D array with dimensions ([X*Y*Z, t]). Finally I have to get this 2D array as the output.

Comment: even with the update, my answer should help. But I also added a simplified solution if data is only one "array" (a python list with the tree or four elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

The update of the question suggests that the function `frontend()` should take only one array (python list). This would be the simplified solution for that case:

```
def frontend(data):
  return [reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, data[:-1]), data[-1]]
```

The first element of the returned list is generated by multiplying all elements in `data`, except the last one (`data[:-1]`). This would be `[x, y]` or `[x, y, z]`. The second element of the returned list is simply the last element of `data` (`data[-1]`). This would be `t` in the 3D and the 4D case.

example usage:

```
>>> frontend([100,50,10,20])
[50000, 20]
>>> frontend([100,50,20])
[5000, 20]
```

### Update for Python 3:

In Python 3, there is no `reduce()` function anymore. Without importing anything, you would need to use a loop:

```
def frontend(data):
  product = 1
  for elem in data[:-1]:
    product = product * elem
  return [product, data[-1]]
```

usage same as above:

```
>>> frontend([100,50,10,20])
[50000, 20]
```

### Previous solutions for a list of tuples:

I am not completely sure, what you mean with "check data.shape". I did interpret it as testing how many dimension one element has. I am showing two versions. The first one is checking the number of values in the first element of data, the second version is simply multiplying all values of one data-element except the last, then adding the last one as the second value for the resulting "2D" element:

```
# example data:
data_5d = [(1,2,3,4,5), (5,6,7,8,9)]
data_4d = [(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8)]
data_3d = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
data_2d = [(1,2), (2,5)]
data_inconsistent = [(1,2,3,5), (8,9)]


# Version handling only 3D and 4D data:
# =====================================

def frontend(data):
  #check data.shape:
  # get number of dimensions by checking first element:
  dimensions = len(data[0])

  #optain values and reshape:
  if dimensions == 4:
    return [[x*y*z, t] for x, y, z, t in data]
  elif dimensions == 3:
    return [[x*y, t] for x, y, t in data]
  else:
    #handle error?
    return []

print "frontend():"
print "5D: ", frontend(data_5d)
print "4D: ", frontend(data_4d)
print "3D: ", frontend(data_3d)
print "2D: ", frontend(data_2d)
# this would raise an exception:
#print frontend(data_inconsistent)


# General Version
# ===============

def frontendx(data):
  return [[reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, elem[:-1]), elem[-1]] for elem in data]

print "\nfrontendx():"
print "5D: ", frontendx(data_5d)
print "4D: ", frontendx(data_4d)
print "3D: ", frontendx(data_3d)
print "2D: ", frontendx(data_2d)
print "?D: ", frontendx(data_inconsistent)
```

Output:

```
frontend():
5D:  []
4D:  [[6, 4], [210, 8]]
3D:  [[2, 3], [20, 6]]
2D:  []

frontendx():
5D:  [[24, 5], [1680, 9]]
4D:  [[6, 4], [210, 8]]
3D:  [[2, 3], [20, 6]]
2D:  [[1, 2], [2, 5]]
?D:  [[6, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution Pascal Rosin. It worked quite well.

Also, I came up with another solution.

Since I was dealing with 4D/3D/2D arrays, I wrote a function on an external script, imported it, and then used it on my main script.

I used ndarray.ndim to find the dimension and appropriately reshape it.

```
# Passing data as input
def frontend(data):
    if data.ndim == 4:
        data = data.reshape([data.shape[0]*data.shape[1]*data.shape[2],data.shape[3]])
        return data
    elif data.ndim == 3:
        data = data.reshape([data.shape[0]*data.shape[1],data.shape[2]])
        return data
    elif data.ndim == 2:
        return data
    else:
        text = 'unrecognized shape'
        print str(text)
```

This works perfectly too.